# If $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\infty$, is it then true that $\lim_{x\to a}f'(x)=\infty$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose on an open interval $(a,b)$, $f(x)$ is differentiable. If $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=+\infty$, is it then true that $\lim_{x\to a}f'(x)=\pm \infty$? If it is, how does one prove this statement? ($a,b\in R$)

Comment: how do i type infinity

Comment: It's not true. Look e.g. at our old friend $\sin \frac{1}{x}$ to search for counterexamples.

Comment: sin1/x is bounded, how is it a counterexample?

Comment: It isn't a counterexample, but you can use it to construct counterexamples. Of course, if you allow $a = -\infty$, then $-x$ can serve as a trivial counterexample.

Comment: a is one end of the open interval, there is no way for it to be the infinity

Comment: f is not defined at a

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without loss of generality, let $a = 0$. Consider

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{x}\left(\frac{3}{2} + \sin \frac{1}{x}\right).$$

Answer (score -1):

Consider $f(x) = \sqrt {-x}$ on $ (-\infty, 0)$. Then $f(x) \to \infty $ as $x\to - \infty $ and $f'(x) \to 0 $.

Comment: $a$ can't be $-\infty$ I guess

Comment: x is approaching a finite value

Comment: If you allowed $-\infty$ you could just take $f(x)=-x$....